# How to create graph from only one column of a HTML table in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have already made column range chart from the min and max values. Now I want to show mean(average) column of the table as scatter plot points on these columnranges. For this purpose I will just need data of the mean column to create scatter points.

I am unsure on how to tackle this problem.

```
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'

    tooltip: {
       formatter : function() {
           return '<strong> Range: </strong>' + this.y + ' to ' +this.x;
       } 
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    }
```

I would like to have scatterpoints showing mean of the min and max values on the columnrange lines of the graph. Also a tooltip displaying the range and average of the numbers would be great.

[The JSfiddle of the columnrange graph is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/abhispatel42/fqugktao/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by following this approach:

- using `Highcharts.Data.prototype.parseTable` get the last column with mean values
- filter mean values to get numbers
- use `chart.addSeries` method on load event to add scatter points

**Code:**

```js
$(function() {

 const table = Highcharts.Data.prototype.parseTable.call({
   options: {
      table: "datatable",
    },
    columns: [],
    dataFound: () => {}
  });
  
  const scatterData = table[3].reduce((filtered, elem) => {
    const value = +elem;
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      filtered.push(value);
    }
    return filtered;
  }, []);
  
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: true,
      events: {
       load: function() {
          this.addSeries({
           type: 'scatter',
            data: scatterData
          })
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Mean difference (d)'
      }
    },
    data: {
      table: 'datatable'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        pointWidth: 5,
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.point.low) {
         return '<strong> Range: </strong>' + this.point.low + ' to ' + this.point.high;
        } else {
         return '<strong> Mean: </strong>' + this.y;
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 40%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 40%; height: 300px; float: right"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Treatment</th>
      <th>Min</th>
      <th>Max</th>
      <th>Mean</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Drug1</td>
      <td>-5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drug2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drug3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drug4</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Drug5</td>
      <td>-2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7znLy09r/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Data#parseTable
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Thank you so much as this is exactly what I wanted. I could have never though it through myself.